# Using python to calculate average of a grouped column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

I have written a Python code to average numbers by groups. Hereby I want to average 5th column grouped by 2nd column.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("test.txt", delimiter=" ")
result = df.groupby(['radii']).mean()
np.savetxt('result.txt', result.values, fmt='%f')
```

My data is:

> no radii len num dens
>
> 1 0.0246136 3.9 0.0006 1.04692
>
> 2 0.0246136 5.9 0.0002 0.348973
>
> 3 0.0738409 7.9 0.0018 1.04692
>
> 4 0.0738409 9.9 0.0012 0.697945
>
> 5 0.123068 3.9 0.0014 0.488562
>
> 6 0.123068 5.9 0.0016 0.558356

But, unfortunately I do not get the second column in the output result (see below):
output result is:

> 1.500000 4.900000 0.000400 0.697947
>
> 3.500000 8.900000 0.001500 0.872432
>
> 5.500000 4.900000 0.001500 0.523459

My expected result is:

> 0.0246136 0.6979465
>
> 0.0738409 0.8724325
>
> 0.123068 0.523459

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to add

```py
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The reason is that the column you're grouping by becomes the index. By resetting the index, the groupby column will become a column in the dataframe.